# Describing the sound of blood drops

Tags: onomatopoeia

I'm searching for a word describing the sound of blood drops falling on someone's shoulder. I found some describing the sound of liquids hitting a surface, such as **tap**, **splat**, and **tuck**. I was going for **splat** but can you give me some other suggestions.

Comment: I'd say ***plop***. if there were a steady flow of drops, as with rain, you might use ***patter*** - "the raindrops *pattered* on the kitchen floor through the open window".

Comment: I doubt there would be a sound.  When my kitchen faucet drips, I put a dishtowel under the drip.  The sound comes when the water droplet lands on the metal of the sink.  In this case, there's no metal, enamel or plastic, just skin or cloth.

Comment: I would say splat/splatter is most appropriate.

Comment: There's nothing special about blood. The word that works for any kind of liquid would work for blood too. What do you call the sound of a leaky faucet?

Comment: Thank you for your answers  WS2 _ aparente001 _ Mitch. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be surprised if a single blood drop made any audible sound hitting something as soft and yielding as human skin, the gentlest of "ticks" on a taut section of fresh perhaps. "Splat" suggests the sound a bucket of blood makes hitting the wall or floor. Repeated drops on the same area, if the person is very still might "plop" as blood falls into pooled blood already lost.